# Unable to return limited text in SOLR Highlight

Tags: solr

My solr documents consists of information as described below:

```
{
    "rid":0,
    "resourceName":"cd05",
    "metadata":"[u'org.apache.tika.parser.DefaultParser', u'org.apache.tika.parser.txt.TXTParser']",
    "content":"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nFurthermore , as an encouragement to revisionist thinking , it manifestly is fair to admit that any fraternity has a constitutional right to refuse to accept persons it dislikes . The Unitarian clergy were an exclusive club of cultivated gentlemen -- as the term was then understood in the Back Bay -- and Parker was definitely not a gentleman , either in theology or in manners . Ezra Stiles Gannett , an honorable representative of the sanhedrin , I see not how a miracle proves a doctrine '' .\n",
    "_version_":1626177165603110912
}
```

I am searching on content and want to use highlight feature of Solr. My search string is `http://localhost:8983/solr/core_name/select?hl.fragsize=10&hl.fl=content&hl=on&indent=on&q=content:*fair\%20to\%20admit*&wt=json`. Despite providing fragsize as parameter I am getting whole `content` in highlight. I only want 10 nearby characters not whole text.

How can I acheive this ?

Comment: Can you show a proper result, including the highlighting section? You ask for the content attribute in the field list (fl), so the whole attribute is always returned in the document section. In the highlighting section, you should see the search hits (marked up with <em> and </em>), plus a pretty short context (approximately 10 characters) around them.